# Unit testing does not fill the component object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new in Angular, and I just implemented on an existing project the unit testing with Karma and Jasmine, so I created the spec.ts component and html as:

```js
describe('CashFlowSalariesComponent', () => {
      let fixture: ComponentFixture < CashFlowSalariesComponent > ;
      let mockCashFlowService;
      let data;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        data = [{
          id: 1006,
          role: "Test",
          ...
        }]

        mockCashFlowService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createTableData'])
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          imports: [
            RouterTestingModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            ToastrModule.forRoot({
              positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
            })
          ],
          declarations: [
            CashFlowSalariesComponent,
          ],
          providers: [{
              provide: ApiService,
              useValue: mockCashFlowService
            }, UserService, ProfileService, VettingStatusService, ApplicationRoleService,
            SeniorityLevelService, PlacementStatusService, EducationLevelService, UtilsService, ShirtSizeService,
            CountryService, CityService, PostalCodeService, StateService, ClientSectorService, JobService, ProfileActivityService, ProfileSalaryActivityService, ClientService, RequestTimeOffService, TimeOffTypeService, PulsecheckDetailService, PulsecheckMasterService,
            PulsecheckQuestionService, ExpenseService, DepartmentService, ExchangeRateService, SkillCategoriesService, ProfileRoleService,
            ToastrService
          ]

        })

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CashFlowSalariesComponent);
      }));

      it('should set salaries data correctly', () => {
        mockCashFlowService.userBelongsTo = 'operations'
        mockCashFlowService.createTableData.and.returnValue(of (data))
        debugger;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.data.length).toBe(1);
      })
```

```html
<div class="row" *ngIf="apiService.utilsService.userBelongsTo('operations')">
  <div class="col-12 my-2">
    <div class="shadow bg-white rounded">
      <div class="card" *ngIf="salariesCard">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row px-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4 class="my-card-title">Employee Salaries</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right d-flex justify-content-end">
              <h5 class="card-title mr-2 my-2">{{ salariesCard.usdExpensesTotal | currency }}</h5>
              <csv-export-button [data]="dataExport" [propertyKeys]="propertyKeysExport" [headerNames]="dataHeadersExport" fileName="Employee Salaries">
              </csv-export-button>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="my-table-wrapper mt-4">

            <table class="table salaries-table">
              <thead class="">
                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let header of dataHeaders" [width]="header.width">{{header.name}}</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let salary of data; index as i" [class.bg-danger]="salary.isPaymentHold">
                  <td scope="row">{{i + 1}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <span class="badge" [class.badge-outline-info]="salary.role == 'Developer'" [class.badge-outline-success]="salary.role == 'Drafter'" [class.badge-outline-warning]="salary.role == 'Admin' || salary.role == 'Recruiter'">
                          {{
                            salary.role == 'Developer' ? 'Dev' :
                            salary.role == 'Drafter' ? 'Draft' :
                            salary.role.trim()
                          }}
                        </span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong class="not-so-strong">{{ salary.name }}</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                      {{ salary.client }}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <input *ngIf="selectedProfile != null && selectedProfile.id == salary.id" type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm text-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedProfileMXNExpense" [disabled]="selectedProfileExpenseCurrency == 1">
                    <div *ngIf="selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id" class="profile-perception">
                      {{ salary.mxnAmount | currency }}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <input *ngIf="selectedProfile != null && selectedProfile.id == salary.id" type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm text-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedProfileUSDExpense" [disabled]="selectedProfileExpenseCurrency == 2">
                    <div *ngIf="selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id" class="profile-perception">
                      {{ salary.usdAmount | currency }}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <select *ngIf="selectedProfile != null && selectedProfile.id == salary.id" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedProfileExpenseCurrency" (ngModelChange)="setSelectedProfileCurrency()">
                      <option value="1">USD</option>
                      <option value="2">MXN</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id">
                      {{ salary.paymentCurrency }}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <!-- Health Insurance Cost -->
                    <input *ngIf="selectedProfile != null && selectedProfile.id == salary.id" type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm text-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedProfileInsuranceExpense">
                    <div *ngIf="selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id" class="profile-expense">
                      {{ salary.mxnInsuranceCost | currency }}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <!-- Net Payment -->
                    <div>
                      {{ salary.mxnNetPayment | currency }}
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <!-- Enrolled in health insurance -->
                    <div>
                      {{ salary.isEnrolledInHealthInsurance ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <div class="d-flex actions-container">
                      <button *ngIf="selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id" (click)=s etProfile(salary.profile) class="btn" ngbTooltip="Edit">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button *ngIf="(selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id) && !salary.isPaymentHold" (click)="holdProfilePayment(profile, true)" class="btn" ngbTooltip="Hold Payment">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-pause"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button *ngIf="(selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id) && salary.isPaymentHold" (click)="holdProfilePayment(profile, false)" class="btn" ngbTooltip="Resume Payment">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-play"></i>
                      </button>
                      <a *ngIf="selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id" [href]="'/profiles/detail/' + salary.id" target="_blank" ngbTooltip="Go to profile" class="btn">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-eye"></i>
                      </a>
                      <button *ngIf="selectedProfile != null && selectedProfile.id == salary.id" class="btn" (click)="saveProfileExpense(salariesCard)" ngbTooltip="Save">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-check"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button *ngIf="selectedProfile != null && selectedProfile.id == salary.id" class="btn" (click)="selectedProfile = null" ngbTooltip="Cancel">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-cancel"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button *ngIf="(selectedProfile == null || selectedProfile.id != salary.id) && !salary.isPaymentHold" (click)="showHistory(salary.profile)" class="btn" ngbTooltip="Salary history">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-currency-usd"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```js
@Component({
  selector: "cash-flow-salaries",
  templateUrl: "./cash-flow-salaries.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./cash-flow-salaries.component.css"],
})
export class CashFlowSalariesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() salariesCard: SalariesCardItem;
  @Input() exchangeRate: number;
  @Input() roleNamesByProfileId: string[];
  @Input() clients: ClientModel[] = [];

  @Output() profileEdited: EventEmitter < number > = new EventEmitter < number > ();

  selectedProfile: ProfileModel = null;
  selectedProfileUSDExpense: string = "";
  selectedProfileMXNExpense: string = "";
  selectedProfileInsuranceExpense: string = "";
  selectedProfileExpenseCurrency: number = 2;
  selectedProfileClientId: number = 0;
  originalSalary: number;

  public dataHeaders = [{
      name: "#",
      width: "6%"
    },
    {
      name: "Role",
      width: "7%"
    },
    {
      name: "Name"
    },
    {
      name: "Client"
    },
    {
      name: "MXN Amount"
    },
    {
      name: "USD Amount"
    },
    {
      name: "Payment Currency",
      width: "8%"
    },
    {
      name: "MXN Insurance Cost"
    },
    {
      name: "MXN Net Payment"
    },
    {
      name: "Is Enrolled in Health Insurance?"
    },
  ];

  public dataHeadersExport = [
    "#",
    "Role",
    "Name",
    "Client",
    "MXN Amount",
    "USD Amount",
    "Payment Currency",
    "MXN Insurance Cost",
    "MXN Net Payment",
    "Is Enrolled in Health Insurance?",
    "Uses TPS",
    "Hiring date",
  ];
  public propertyKeys: string[];
  public propertyKeysExport: string[];

  public data = [];
  public dataExport = [];
  constructor(
    public apiService: ApiService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
 
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.createTableData();
  }

  createTableData() {
    this.propertyKeys = Object.keys(new SalaryDataModel());
    this.data =
      this.salariesCard && this.salariesCard.shownProfiles ?
      this.salariesCard.shownProfiles.map((p) => {
        let salary: SalaryDataModel = new SalaryDataModel();
        salary.id = p.id;
        salary.role = this.roleNamesByProfileId[p.id];
        salary.name = p.firstName + " " + p.lastName;
        salary.client = this.salariesCard.getClientName(p);
        salary.mxnAmount =
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalaryCurrencyId == 2 ?
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalary :
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalary * this.exchangeRate;
        salary.usdAmount =
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalaryCurrencyId == 1 ?
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalary :
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalary / this.exchangeRate;
        salary.paymentCurrency =
          p.monthlyOfferedNetSalaryCurrencyId == 1 ? "USD" : "MXN";
        salary.mxnInsuranceCost = p.monthlyInsuranceCost;
        salary.mxnNetPayment = this.getNetPayment(p);
        salary.isEnrolledInHealthInsurance =
          p.isEnrolledInHealthInsuranceBonus;
        salary.isPaymentHold = p.isPaymentHold;

        salary.profile = p;

        return salary;
      }) :
      null;
  }


export class SalaryDataModel {
  id: number = 0;
  role: string = "";
  name: string = "";
  client: string = "";
  mxnAmount: number = 0;
  usdAmount: number = 0;
  paymentCurrency: string = "";
  mxnInsuranceCost: number = 0;
  mxnNetPayment: number = 0;
  isEnrolledInHealthInsurance ? : boolean = false;
  isPaymentHold: boolean = false;
  profile: ProfileModel;
}
export class SalaryDataModelExport {
  id: string = "";
  role: string = "";
  name: string = "";
  client: string = "";
  mxnAmount: number = 0;
  usdAmount: number = 0;
  paymentCurrency: string = "";
  mxnInsuranceCost: number = 0;
  mxnNetPayment: number = 0;
  isEnrolledInHealthInsurance ? : boolean = false;
  profile: ProfileModel;
  TXP: string = "";
  HiringDate: string = "";
}
```

So, as you can see I try to access to:
`expect(fixture.componentInstance.data.length).toBe(1);`, but the length is always 0, this is weird because I specifying the value on:

```
mockCashFlowService.createTableData.and.returnValue(of(data))
```

Why the data value is not detecting that I set the property on the test?

Comment: Move `mockCashFlowService.createTableData.and.returnValue(of (data))` where you are setting up the mock data for `data`

Comment: Just at the unit testing after declare data @Andres2142